# Shrink columns of CSS grid at the same rate

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using a css grid. Columns and rows of this grid are set to "auto". Each cell in the grid contains (among other things) an image that determines the dimensions.

The grid looks like this:
[image]
The problem is: when I reduce the screen size, the ratio of the grid cells is not maintained. It seems like the leftmost column is shrunk first:

[image]

This leads to ugly wholes in the grid. How can I ensure that the grid is growing and shrinking consistently while ideally keeping the images determining the appearance?

Here is a simple version of the grid CSS with an accompanying [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfu7oped/).

```
   .grid {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    grid-gap: 12px 12px;
    }

    .element_1 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
    }
    .element_2 {
          grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 4;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }
    .element_3 {
      grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 5;
    }
    .element_4 {
          grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 4;
        grid-row-start: 4;
        grid-row-end: 5;
    }

    .img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution, your css file

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid > div img {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.element_1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.element_1 img {
  padding-top:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
.element_2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.element_2 img {
  padding-top:0;
  padding-right:0;
}
.element_3 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.element_3 img {
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
.element_4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.element_4 img {
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-right:0;
}

.img-responsive {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .img-responsive {
    padding:3px;
  }
}
```

you can see running example & play with source code here [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dinulit/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Could you explain a little how these paddings fix the issue?

Comment: Please, up vote so I can unlock new features in this site. Now my explanation, first of all grid, flex and many of those are in developing phase, not predictable, but still have much awesome layouts. In your code grid-gap was the real issue may be it was not calculating correct values. So I just go little back in css days and used those styles fully stable in all browsers, for gave padding around image 6px so it will be double on side where two elements collision 6+6=12px, also we can used box-sizing to any element so it will be calculate own width after deduction of padding values.

Comment: I also found inline element didn't behave well so for all images I used inline-block. By default any IMG element display property set to inline in most of browser.